# Fos User bundle duplicate defination of database

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

when i update the database through this
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
it gives the exception that is given below
MappingException: Duplicate definition of column 'email' on entity 'Dashboard\UserBundle\Entity\User' in a field or discriminator column mapping
my user.php is given below

```
<?php
// src/Dashboard/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace Dashboard\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints AS Assert;
use Dashboard\UserBundle\Entity\User;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="acme_user")
* @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
* @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="email", column=@ORM\Column(type="string", name="email", length=255, unique=false, nullable=true)),
* @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="emailCanonical", column=@ORM\Column(type="string", name="email_canonical", length=255, unique=false, nullable=true))
* })
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
protected $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $Password;

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->plainPassword;
}

public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->plainPassword = $password;
}

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // your own logic
}
}
```

How to remove this exception?

Answer (score 2):

Remove $email and his getter and setter

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
protected $email;
```

It's already in BaseUser